# Can't create a Kotlin class or file

Tags: kotlin

I just started to learn Kotlin, but the course that I'm using seems to be outdated.

When I try to follow its steps to create a class or file, the option is not there, instead there are Kotlin Script ou Worksheet.

trying right click on src

[image: 1]

neither right clicking on main

[image: 2]

I'm using IntelliJ 2021.1.2 and JDK version 16

Comment: This is most likely not because of your course being outdated. You haven't set up your project correctly. I remember coming across a similar question, but I can't find it right now...

Comment: Wow, thanks a lot, set up my project differently and worked. Thanks a lot!

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should choose android not project first

[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vp45t.png)